# PowerShell: Long list of conditions using logial operators elegantly

Tags: powershell, coding-style, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I think that there must be a more elegant way to get this done
Readability is a plus, and simplicity is beautiful.
I think what I ended up with is somewhat readable.
Can't help but think there's a better way to do this.

Suggestions?

Reading records from a log to find the records which fall into certain time periods.

```
<#
from log get records which match any the following sets of conditions

        Day of the week is
            Monday through Thursday
                AND time of day is
                    at or after 07:00 and before 08:00
                    OR
                    after 17:00 and at or before 22:00
    OR
        Day of the week is
            Friday
                AND time of day is
                    at or after 07:00 and before 08:00
    OR
        Day of the week is
            Saturday
                AND time of day is
                    at or after 11:00 and at or before 16:00
    OR
        Day of the week is
            Sunday
                AND time of day is
                    at or after 18:00 and at or before 23:00
#>

$201503_OC = $201503 |?{
    (   (   (   ( [int]($_.TimeStamp.DayOfWeek) -ge 1   ) `
                    -and ( [int]($_.TimeStamp.DayOfWeek) -le 4  )   ) `
            -and (  (   (   ($_.TimeStamp.TimeOfDay) -ge "07:00"    ) `
                    -and (  ($_.TimeStamp.TimeOfDay) -lt "08:00"    )   ) `
                -or (   (   ($_.TimeStamp.TimeOfDay) -gt "17:00"    ) `
                    -and (  ($_.TimeStamp.TimeOfDay) -le "22:00"    )   )   )   ) `
        -or (   (   [int]($_.TimeStamp.DayOfWeek) -eq 5 ) `
            -and (  (   ($_.TimeStamp.TimeOfDay) -ge "07:00"    ) `
                -and (  ($_.TimeStamp.TimeOfDay) -le "08:00"    )   )   ) `
        -or (   (   [int]($_.TimeStamp.DayOfWeek) -eq 6 ) `
            -and (  (   ($_.TimeStamp.TimeOfDay) -ge "11:00"    ) `
                -and (  ($_.TimeStamp.TimeOfDay) -le "16:00"    )   )   ) `
        -or (   (   [int]($_.TimeStamp.DayOfWeek) -eq 0 ) `
            -and (  (   ($_.TimeStamp.TimeOfDay) -ge "18:00"    ) `
                -and (  ($_.TimeStamp.TimeOfDay) -le "23:00"    )   )   )   ) `
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put your complex conditionals in a function or a scriptproperty/scriptmethod.

It sort of looks like each of the top level condition trees that are separated by `OR` refer to some meaningful condition for you, is that right? They aren't named as such, so I will make up names for them to demonstrate:

#### David

```
Day of the week is
        Monday through Thursday
            AND time of day is
                at or after 07:00 and before 08:00
                OR
                after 17:00 and at or before 22:00
```

#### Gerald

```
Day of the week is
        Friday
            AND time of day is
                at or after 07:00 and before 08:00
```

#### Daniel

```
Day of the week is
        Saturday
            AND time of day is
                at or after 11:00 and at or before 16:00
```

#### Darian

```
Day of the week is
        Sunday
            AND time of day is
                at or after 18:00 and at or before 23:00
```

```powershell
$201503 | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name David -Value {
(   (   ( [int]($this.TimeStamp.DayOfWeek) -ge 1   ) `
                    -and ( [int]($this.TimeStamp.DayOfWeek) -le 4  )   ) `
            -and (  (   (   ($this.TimeStamp.TimeOfDay) -ge "07:00"    ) `
                    -and (  ($this.TimeStamp.TimeOfDay) -lt "08:00"    )   ) `
                -or (   (   ($this.TimeStamp.TimeOfDay) -gt "17:00"    ) `
                    -and (  ($this.TimeStamp.TimeOfDay) -le "22:00"    )   )   )
}
```

Not pictured: code to implement the Gerald, Daniel, and Darian ScriptProperties.

```powershell
$201503_OC = $201503 | ? { $_.David -or $_.Gerald -or $_.Daniel -or $_.Darian }
```

Of course the usefulness of this depends on how you're using it, but if you give the conditionals more meaningful names, like "HappyHour" or "WeekendBrowsers" or whatever, then the resulting logic code is far more readable, even if the code that makes up the conditionals is still tough to parse.

Comment: I will quickly add more context by naming the sets of conditions.
I've not used ScriptProperty before. I am going to play around with it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using `-contains` to simplify the range checks, and moving the digits to the LH side to eliminate casting `.DayOfWeek` to `[int]`.  Since the time ranges are on hour boundaries, the time comparisons can be simplified by just using the `.Hour` property.

```
$201503_OC = $201503 |
 Where {
  ( 1..4 -contains $_.DayOfWeek -and 17..21 + 7 -contains $_.Hour ) -or
  ( 5 -eq $_.DayOfWeek -and 7 -eq $_.Hour ) -or
  ( 6 -eq $_.DayOfWeek -and 11..15 -contains $_.Hour ) -or
  ( 0 -eq $_.DayOfWeek -and 18..22 -contains $_.Hour )
 }
```

Comment: Nice! Great use of ranges. +1

Comment: I really like that. Thank you.